# How to do downcasting in nhibernate inheritance

Tags: inheritance, nhibernate

I have two classes **Manager** and **Employee**, and two tables for them in database. **Manager class inherits Employee class**. I want to **convert** an Employee to a Manager. Is there any way I can do this in **nhibernate**?

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public virtual string CabinNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to convert an employee with ID `employeeId` to a Manager and save it in database:

```
var employee = Repository.Get<DomainModel.Models.Sadhak>(employeeId);
DomainModel.Models.Manager manager = (DomainModel.Models.Manager) employee;
manager.CabinNumber = "A65";
session.Delete(employee);
session.SaveOrUpdate(manager);
```

Comment: Please post a piece of code as sample.

Comment: You can't do this with C# code. You can try using raw SQL to update the discriminator value though, but that might really screw up the first level cache. You may be better off deleting + recreating the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that in NHibernate, it assumes that once you have created an entity, it is always of that type.